# Passing header on redirect to angular api from spring boot API

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http-headers

We have angular API and springboot project bundled together as single war. The dist content of angular app is placed in classes/static/angularUrl folder of springboot build while building the project. Below is the snapshot of the build.gradle:

```
from('../angularApp/dist') {
        into 'BOOT-INF/classes/static/angularUrl'
    }
```

We have no API on springboot starting with "angularUrl" and the springboot is configured to send the request to angularUrl/index.html whenever it encounters 404 error as below:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurator implements WebMvcConfigurer ,WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController(Constant.NOT_FOUND_URL).setViewName("forward:/angularUrl/index.html")
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, Constant.NOT_FOUND_URL));     
    }
}
```

So whenever we enter the URL ip:port/angularUrl, since there is no API on springboot side with this url, it gives 404 and with above springboot configuration the angular app gets loaded via index.html and the home page is loaded and this is how our application home page is accessed. So any URL path will lead to loading of angular homepage.

Now the issue I am facing is that I want to send some http request parameters and http headers as soon as angular gets loaded. So, how do I configure springboot to send all the incoming http request parameters and http header to the angular app when it encounters 404

Comment: Any help would be appreciated